# Using R: How to repeat a function I made thousands of times keeping a count of which number it ends on for each repeat

Tags: r

Here's the code I made so far:

```
z = vector()
for(i in 1:20){
  Alkie = function(T=20, lambda=2.5, k=2, mu=3) {
    t = 0
    N = 0
    i = 1
    A.t = rexp(1, lambda)
    D.t = Inf
    while(t[i] < T) {
      t[i+1] = min(A.t, D.t)
      N[i+1] = N[i] + ifelse(A.t < D.t, 1, -1)
      if(A.t < D.t) {
        A.t = A.t + rexp(1,lambda)
        if(N[i+1] == 1) D.t = t[i+1] + rgamma(1, k, mu)
        if(N[i+1] == 6) D.t = t[i+1] + rgamma(1, 0, mu)
      }
      else
        D.t = ifelse(N[i+1] == 0, Inf, t[i+1] + rgamma(1, k, mu))
      i = i + 1
    }
    cbind(t=t, N=N)
  }

x = Alkie(T=20, lambda=2.5, k=2, mu=3)
n = nrow(x)
plot(c(x[1,1], rep(x[-1,1], each=2), x[n,1]), rep(x[,2], each=2), type="l", 
xlab="t(mins)", ylab="N(t)", col="blue")
```

How do I store the counts?

Comment: You have a missing "}" in your script.

Comment: Why not write the count into a file in shared memory?

Comment: The short answer is to use [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the counts